# () is not convertible to String

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a simple clock app and I'm running into an issue.

```
@IBAction func toggle(sender: UISwitch) {

    func formatADate() {
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
        let date = NSDate()
        let output = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
        println(output)
    }

    let clockString: String = formatADate()

    clockFace.hidden = false
    clockFace.text = clockString
}
```

But I keep getting the error `() is not convertible to String`. Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 6):

The `formatADate` function is declared as taking no parameters and returning void (i.e. nothing), whereas in this line

```
let clockString: String = formatADate()
```

you are assigning its return value (void) to a string.

You just have to declare that function as returning a string:

```
    func formatADate() -> String {
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
        let date = NSDate()
        let output = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
        println(output)

        return output            
    }
```

I'm making the assumption that `output` is what you want it to return - if not, change accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Your `formatADate` function should be defined as returning a `String`

```
func formatADate()-> String { // use -> to show returned type
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
    let date = NSDate()
    let output = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    return output // return string type
}

let clockString: String = formatADate()
```